# Insert JSON in MySQL using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a JSON file with data that I'd like to insert in my MySQL table using SQLAlchemy.
The point is that I'm trying to figure out if is there a equivalent method for executemany (mysql.connector) in SQLAlchemy, as I have to use the last one.

```
data = []
with open('vehicle_data_usa_2014-2016.json', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
try:
    sql = "INSERT INTO vehicle (carModelName, engineType, MPGhighway, MPGcity) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
    val = [(x["model_id"], x["engine_type"], x["mpg_highway"], x["mpg_city"]) for x in data]
    with engine.begin() as conn:
        conn.execute(statement=text(sql,val))
except exc.SQLAlchemyError as e:
    err = str(e.__dic__['orig'])
    print('Error while connecting to MySQL', err)
```

The output is the following:
TypeError: text() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run a plain text query that uses the "format" [paramstyle](https://peps.python.org/pep-0249/#paramstyle) (`%s`) then you should use `.exec_driver_sql()` like this:

```py
sql = "INSERT INTO vehicle (carModelName, engineType, MPGhighway, MPGcity) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
val = [(x["model_id"], x["engine_type"], x["mpg_highway"], x["mpg_city"]) for x in data]
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.exec_driver_sql(sql, val)
```